# Cannot redirect the ouput of hwclock -r command

Tags: bash, shell, hwclock

I am implementing a shell script and I want to analyse the output shown by hwclock -r (--show) command which displays the RTC time and date.

To do that I tried things like: hwclock -r | grep -v "grep" | grep "error" > /dev/null
to see if an error happened while reading RTC registers.

The problem is that output is only and always forwarded to console. I tried to forward output to a file then analyse its content and I also tried to use tee -a command to direct output to both console and a file, but with no success.

Is there a solution to that or an explanation to what is happening with hwclock -r command.

In advance Thank you.

Comment: What is the output you see in the console?

Comment: The output is not the problem. Regardless of RTC status I want to redirect output so I can analyse and do some decisions based on the results.

Comment: Well, it's up to you if you do or do not want to provide additional information to help get your question answered. I'll just point out that some error messages can be written to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: Thanks Lev, you reminded me a fundamental point which is error messages. I just solved it by forwarding error messages to a file then make the analysis. hwclock -r 2> file.txt; grep -v "grep" | grep "error" > /dev/null will do the job. I completely forgot error messages story, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I just solved it by forwarding error messages to a file then make the analysis.
>
> `hwclock -r 2> file.txt; grep -v "grep" | grep "error" > /dev/null` will do the job.

You omitted `file.txt` in the first `grep`.

If you just want to check for "error", with a not too old `bash` this will also do, in a shorter way:

```
hwclock -r |& grep error >/dev/null
```